# Flutter checkbox how to set OutlinedBorder

Tags: flutter

Flutter checkbox how to set OutlinedBorder, I want implement a Checkbox with custom border raduis.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to solve this problem since flutter doesn't have a radius field in the checkbox api. But following are the ways that you can try

1. Use Icons instead of checkboxs and giev them round shape
2. Modify the existing Material checkbox code and add your own checkbox widget with the following

```
const Radius _kEdgeRadius = Radius.circular(1.0) to Radius.circular(100).
```

3. Make the border of the checkbox transparent and create a container behind it and give a rounded border to the container

Comment: Sorry, sir. latest flutter already have a `shape` param in checkbox, I just don't know how to use it. If you know, pls update your answer.

Comment: It does not have any here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html

Comment: You need dev branch. I already solved this.